# Scrapy item yields repeat values

Tags: duplicates, scrapy, yield

I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction with this problem.
Below is a spider that:
1. crawls listing page and retrieves each record's summary info (10 rows/page)
2. follows the URL for to extract detailed info on each individual record's page
3. goes to the next listing page

Problem: each record's detailed info is extracting fine but each record contains the summary info of the last record from the same listing page.

Simplified example:

```
URL    DA     Detail1        Detail2
9      9      0              0
9      9      1              1
9      9      2              2
9      9      3              3
9      9      4              4
9      9      5              5
9      9      6              6
9      9      7              7
9      9      8              8
9      9      9              9
```

With the scrapy shell, I can iterate through manually and get the correct values as shown below:

```
import scrapy
from cbury_scrapy.items import DA

for row in response.xpath('//table/tr[@class="datrack_resultrow_odd" or @class="datrack_resultrow_even"]'):
    r = scrapy.Selector(text=row.extract(), type="html")
    print r.xpath('//td[@class="datrack_danumber_cell"]//text()').extract_first(), r.xpath('//td[@class="datrack_danumber_cell"]//@href').extract_first()[-5:]
```

Output

```
SC-18/2016 HQQM=
DA-190/2016 HQwQ=
DA-192/2016 HQAk=
S68-122/2016 HQgM=
DA-191/2016 HQgc=
DA-223/2015/A HQQY=
DA-81/2016/A GSgY=
PCA-111/2016 GSwU=
PCD-101/2016 GSwM=
PCD-100/2016 GRAc=
```

When the spider is run, the last record summary details will repeat for each record on the same listing page. Please see the spider below, the offending method seems to be the first 10 lines of the `parse` method.

```
""" Run under bash with:
timenow=`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`; scrapy runspider cbury_spider.py -o cbury-scrape-$timenow.csv
Problems? Interactively check Xpaths etc.:
scrapy shell "http://datrack.canterbury.nsw.gov.au/cgi/datrack.pl?search=search&sortfield=^metadata.date_lodged""""
import scrapy
from cbury_scrapy.items import DA

def td_text_after(label, response):
    """ retrieves text from first td following a td containing a label e.g.:"""
    return response.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + label + "')]/following-sibling::td//text()").extract_first()

class CburySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # scrapy.Spider attributes
    name = "cbury"
    allowed_domains = ["datrack.canterbury.nsw.gov.au"]
    start_urls = ["http://datrack.canterbury.nsw.gov.au/cgi/datrack.pl?search=search&sortfield=^metadata.date_lodged",]
# required for unicode character replacement of '$' and ',' in est_cost
translation_table = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '$,'), None)
da = DA()        
da['lga'] = u"Canterbury"


def parse(self, response):
    """ Retrieve DA no., URL and address for DA on summary list page """
    for row in response.xpath('//table/tr[@class="datrack_resultrow_odd" or @class="datrack_resultrow_even"]'):
        r = scrapy.Selector(text=row.extract(), type="html")
        self.da['da_no'] = r.xpath('//td[@class="datrack_danumber_cell"]//text()').extract_first()
        self.da['house_no'] = r.xpath('//td[@class="datrack_houseno_cell"]//text()').extract_first()
        self.da['street'] = r.xpath('//td[@class="datrack_street_cell"]//text()').extract_first()
        self.da['town'] = r.xpath('//td[@class="datrack_town_cell"]//text()').extract_first()
        self.da['url'] = r.xpath('//td[@class="datrack_danumber_cell"]//@href').extract_first()

        # then retrieve remaining DA details from the detail page
        yield scrapy.Request(self.da['url'], callback=self.parse_da_page)

    # follow next page link if one exists
    next_page = response.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Next')]/@href").extract_first()
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, self.parse)


def parse_da_page(self, response):  
    """ Retrieve DA information from its detail page """        
    labels = { 'date_lodged': 'Date Lodged:', 'desc_full': 'Description:', 
               'est_cost': 'Estimated Cost:', 'status': 'Status:',
               'date_determined': 'Date Determined:', 'decision': 'Decision:',
               'officer': 'Responsible Officer:' }

    # map DA fields with those in the following <td> elements on the page
    for i in labels:
        self.da[i] = td_text_after(labels[i], response)

    # convert est_cost text to int for easier sheet import "12,000" -> 12000
    if self.da['est_cost'] != None:
        self.da['est_cost'] = int(self.da['est_cost'].translate(self.translation_table))

    # Get people data from 'Names' table with 'Role' heading
    self.da['names'] = []
    for row in response.xpath('//table/tr[th[1]="Role"]/following-sibling::tr'):    
        da_name = {}
        da_name['role'] = row.xpath('normalize-space(./td[1])').extract_first()            
        da_name['name_no'] = row.xpath('normalize-space(./td[2])').extract_first()
        da_name['full_name'] = row.xpath('normalize-space(./td[3])').extract_first()
        self.da['names'].append(da_name)

    yield self.da
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's possible that the 'or' in your xpath selection is throwing things off.

Comment: It seems that when I step through the shell statements (2nd code box above), the correct values are extracted. Can you elaborate Benjamin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy is asynchronous, once you've submitted a request there's no guarantee when that request will be actioned. Because of this your self.da is unreliable for passing data to parse_da_page. Instead create `da_items = DA()` in your parse routine and pass it in the request as meta.

```
for row in response.xpath(...):
    da_items = DA()
    da_items['street'] = row.xpath(...)
    ...
    da_items['url'] = row.xpath(...)
    yield scrapy.Request(da_items['url'], callback=self.parse_da_page, meta=da_items)
```

Then in parse_da_page you can retrieve these values using `response.meta['street']` etc.. Have a look at [the docs here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta).

Note also that your line `r = scrapy.Selector(text=row.extract(), type="html")` is redundant, you can simply use the variable `row` directly as I've done in my example above.

Comment: Thank you Steve! I implemented your advice into the spider and marked yours as the answer.
Note, I found removing the 'redundant' line results in only the first row extracted for each iteration of the for block; you might want to revise or remove this from the answer.
The original shell statements (posted above) seem to work though. Please see the output at: 
http://pastebin.com/NDPauW72

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I've had a look at your output on pastebin and I have an explanation. In the for loop the xpaths start with // which means 'from the start of the document'. Inside the loop the variable `row` is basically a pointer into the original html page so on each loop it looks for td starting at the very top of the page and always finds the first one. To do a relative xpath either start it with row.xpath('.//td[...' (leading full stop) or omit the forward slashes altogether, row.xpath('td[...'. Either of these xpath searches will start from the tr.